# Error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument type [java.lang.String]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jetty

I've been struggling to find out the solution with this error for 2 weeks. Could you help me what happened

Here is the error stack trace:

> "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument type
>   [java.lang.String] not available, and parameter name information not
>   found in class file either.\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.updateNamedValueInfo(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:138)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.getNamedValueInfo(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:117)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:84)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)\r\n\tat
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)\r\n\tat
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:82)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:294)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1476)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)\r\n\tat
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\r\n"

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Helpful may be ["how to ask good questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Users here are way more ready to help if you provide [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with some input and the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely trying to past argument as a String somewhere where it should not be accepting String as a parameter or could be not accepting any parameters at all.

As one of the comment said, can you post your codes here? The logs are not telling as well which of your specific class is having an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have some Spring MVC controllers and expect that Spring matches controller method arguments and request parameters by name automatically.

According to this article [enter link description here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/parameter-name-discoverer.html) this only works if your code has been compiled with debugging information (javac -g options).

I've also a hard time with this issue. It worked in my IDE, but not when deploying an ant build to a tomcat. When I tried to remote debug the tomcat and therefore added the javac debug options, it suddenly worked. However, i did not see the relation of the debug option and the issue I was looking for ;-)

Comment: thanks, I found the root cause, that's java version in my pom.xml. After updating the java version from 8 to 7, it works well

Answer (score 1):

Actually here the String type is not available it means like if we give parameters :

```
@Requestparam(value = "myString") String myString
```

if we give it like  `@Requestparam` String myString most probably will get that error.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same error when the method missed to add @RequestParam  annotation against the string. The error is generated when we started to use the Ant Build through Jenkins. When export WAR file through Eclipse IDE, it will not arise.